# Find where is masked in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, masked-array

I want to get the position in a masked array.
Like this

```
wt[chl > 10] = 3
wt[(chl < 10) & (chl > 5)] = 2
wt[(chl < 5)] = 1
wt[(chl is masked )]=0
```

wt and chl is in the same shape. I want to give wt value according to the value and attribute(masked or not) of chl.

Does anyone know what I should do?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`argwhere` returns the indices where a value is non-zero, so if the shapes are equal,

```
wt[np.argwhere(chi)] = 0
```

should zero `wt` where `chi` is nonzero (and `~np.argwhere(chi)` zeroes the indices where `chi` *is* zero).

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `mask` attribute of `chl` directly and use it as an index:

```
wt[chl.mask] = 0
```

Comment: I replaced that, Thank you